# Setting JVM Variable on WAS 8.5

Tags: jvm, websphere

I have to set a `JVM Variable on WAS 8.5` and then access that variable for configuration purposes in a Web Application.
  I followed the IBM docs and I went to

```
 Servers > Application Servers > server1 > process definitions > jvm
```

I  added the new parameter in the Generics `JVM arguments -dmyPath=c:\config`

But when I try to access the value doing `System.getProperty("myPath")` it always returns me a null value. Have you got any clues about that?

Comment: Do you actually mean `-D`?  What does `System.getProperties()` contain? What does the `genericJvmArguments` attribute in the `<jvmEntries>` element of PROFILE_HOME/cells/CELL/nodes/NODE/servers/SERVER/server.xml contain?

Comment: Yes I meant -D in upper case.

Comment: Sorry I've found the problem, I forgot to restart the server, I thought that it was able to do it on the fly, thank you and sorry again!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it figured out.